# Create multiple php commands (Prestashop)

Tags: php, prestashop

I develop a module for a prestashop 1.5 to manage product subscriptions. I am looking to create x order based on what customer to select 3 months, 6 months or 12 months. I already made the logic to recover what was selected I just miss to create the x commands here is what I already did.

```
public function newBox($theCart, $referencesProducts, $subscribeMonth)
{
    $nbMonth = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $subscribeMonth);

    foreach ($referencesProducts as $referencesProduct) {
        $ids_product[] = Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT id_product FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product WHERE reference =\''.$referencesProduct.'\'');
    }

    // Si le nbMonth est égale à 1 an alors on applique un resultat à 12 (mois)
    if ($nbMonth == 1) {
        $productSelected = array_slice($ids_product, 0, 12);
    } else {
        $productSelected = array_slice($ids_product, 0, $nbMonth);
    }

    // On créer les commandes
    $order = new Order();

    $order->id_customer = $theCart->id_customer;
    $order->id_shop = $theCart->id_shop;
    $order->id_currency = $theCart->id_currency;
    $order->id_lang = $theCart->id_lang;
    $order->id_address_invoice = $theCart->id_address_invoice;
    $order->id_address_delivery = $theCart->id_address_delivery;


}
```

In my code I retrieve the list of the products that for each order, if subscription 3 months I recover a table of 3 products if subscription 6 months I recover an array of 6 products. So I have to integrate 1 product per order, how can I do that?

Comment: Use a _loop_ …? Not really sure what more to tell you on such an unspecific question.

Answer (score 0):

I find how to do it here code.

Thank you.

```
public function newBox($theCart, $referencesProducts, $subscribeMonth, $showDate)
{
    $reference = Order::generateReference();
    $nbMonth = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $subscribeMonth);
    foreach ($referencesProducts as $referencesProduct) {
        $ids_product[] = Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT id_product FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product WHERE reference =\'' . $referencesProduct . '\'');
    }

    // Si le nbMonth est égale à 1 an alors on applique un resultat à 12 (mois)
    if ($nbMonth == 1) {
        $productSelected = array_slice($ids_product, 0, 12);
    } else {
        $productSelected = array_slice($ids_product, 0, $nbMonth);
    }

    foreach ($productSelected as $products) {

        $this->calculDate($showDate);

        // On créer les commandes
        $order = new Order();

        $order->product_list = $products;

        $order->id_customer = (int)$theCart->id_customer;
        $order->id_address_invoice = (int)$theCart->id_address_invoice;
        $order->id_address_delivery = (int)$theCart->id_address_delivery;
        $order->id_currency = $theCart->id_currency;
        $order->id_carrier = $theCart->id_carrier;
        $order->id_lang = (int)$theCart->id_lang;
        $order->id_cart = (int)$theCart->id;
        $order->reference = $reference;
        $order->id_shop = (int)$theCart->id_shop;
        $order->id_shop_group = (int)$theCart->id_shop_group;
        $order->current_state = 2;

        $order->payment = "Unknown";
        $order->module = "Unknown";

        $order->secure_key = $theCart->secure_key;
        $order->conversion_rate = 1;

        $order->invoice_number = 0;
        $order->delivery_number = 0;
        $order->valid = 0;

        $order->date_add = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $order->date_upd = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

        $order->recyclable = $theCart->recyclable;
        $order->gift = (int)$theCart->gift;
        $order->gift_message = $theCart->gift_message;
        $order->mobile_theme = $theCart->mobile_theme;
        $order->total_paid_real = 0;

        $order->total_products = 0;
        $order->total_products_wt = 0;

        $order->total_discounts_tax_excl = 0;
        $order->total_discounts_tax_incl = 0;
        $order->total_discounts = 0;

        $order->total_shipping_tax_excl = 0;
        $order->total_shipping_tax_incl = 0;
        $order->total_shipping = 0;

        $order->total_wrapping_tax_excl = 0;
        $order->total_wrapping_tax_incl = 0;
        $order->total_wrapping = 0;

        $order->total_paid_tax_excl = 0;
        $order->total_paid_tax_incl = 0;
        $order->total_paid = 0;

        $order->invoice_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
        $order->delivery_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

        // Creating order
        $result = $order->add();

        if (!$result)
            throw new PrestaShopException('Can\'t save Order');
    }
}
```